# Google AMP: Hide header on scroll possible?

Tags: amp-html

Help required from people working on Google-AMP.
I am trying to hide the navbar while scrolling down. and if while scrolling up show it again.
I'm trying to hide header

```
<nav id="navToHide">Nvabar</nav>
```

AMP Animation Code my shote:

```
<amp-animation id="hideNav" layout="nodisplay">
    <script type="application/json">
        {
        "duration": "200ms",
        "fill": "forwards",
        "iterations": "1",
        "direction": "alternate",
        "animations": [{
            "selector": "#navToHide",
            "keyframes": [{
                "transform": "translateY(-180px)"
            }]
        }]
        }
    </script>
</amp-animation>
```

AMP position observer code:

```
<amp-position-observer on="enter:select-item1.start" layout="nodisplay"></amp-position-observer>
```

I wanna make something similar to navbar hide on scrolling.
Like this example below.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_hide_scroll.asp

I'm trying to avoid javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a really simple way to do this using the [amp-fx-collection](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-fx-collection/)'s [float-in](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-fx-collection/#float-in-top,-float-in-bottom) attribute.

Add the required `<amp-fx-collection>` script to the head of the page:

`<script async custom-element="amp-fx-collection" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-fx-collection-0.1.js"></script>`

And apply the `amp-fx='float-in-top'` attribute to your `<nav>` element.

You can see it demonstrated in this video:

[AMP Conf 2019, amp.dev live!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5XtCAWh31c)

Comment: Thank you, man, it's work you also must have the following CSS properties:
position: fixed 
overflow: hidden 
if it's top, top: 0 
if it's bottom, bottom: 0